# TabBarController status bar issue in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, statusbar

[image]I added the UITabBarController view on the UIWindow. TabBarController view is messing up with Status Bar. The TabBarController is in the MainWindow.xib. How can i fix this?

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nearbySplit, mySplit, allSplit, messageSplit, nil];
tabController.selectedIndex = 0;
    window.rootViewController = tabController;
    [window addSubview:tabController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: i added the screenshot, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the this code in view controller

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;   // iOS 7 specific
```

in your **viewDidLoad** method.